# How to search a list of groups using facebook APIs

Tags: facebook

I need to programmatically search a list of Groups using Facebook APIs. It looks like starting from version 19 of facebook graph APIs, it is not possible to search a list of groups as permission "groups_show_list" has been removed from the platform. Is that correct?

Any hint how can I get this done?

Thanks

I tried following API with User Access Token

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=programming&type=group

But it does not work.